# Is Time Resolution always the best in Continuous Wavelet Transform (CWT)?

Tags: wavelet, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

Does wavelet move a sample point at a time in CWT? This seems to have the best time resolution at all time regardless of what scale is. In the example below, signal length is 2048, for whatever scale value, the calculated *coef* has a length of 2048.

```
import pywt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

# Define signal
fs = 1024.0
dt = 1 / fs
signal_freuqncy = 100
scale = np.arange(2, 256)
wavelet = 'morl'

t = np.linspace(0, 2, int(2 * fs))
y = np.sin(signal_freuqncy*2*np.pi*t)

# Calculate continuous wavelet transform
coef, freqs = pywt.cwt(y, scale, wavelet, dt)

# Show w.r.t. time and frequency
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.pcolor(t, freqs, coef, shading = 'flat', cmap = 'jet')

# Set yscale, ylim and labels
# plt.yscale('log')
# plt.ylim([0, 20])
plt.ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')

cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Energy Intensity')
plt.show()
```

If my guess is right, it is contradictory to my previous understanding that we use expanded wavelet for low freq. component because we want good freq. resolution but poor time resolution at low freq. range. Like shown in the picture.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: I disagree, it's about understanding the functions in one python package.

Comment: No, it's about understanding the math that happens to be implemented in a Python package among others.